# Microsoft Dynamics GP report writer Calculated fields

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

Does anyone know how to add Tax Commodity code which is in IV00101 (Item Master table) on  to SOP invoice as a calculated field.

I could go create a new calculated field and then select 'Item Master' from Fields --> Resources,then select 'Tax Commodity Code' to be added as a new calculated field. this does create a XML field but does not pull through a value when placed on the invoice.

I'm sure there is a way to do this.....it'd be great if anyone could help
Thanks

Comment: Are you editing the report inside your own custom Dexterity dictionary or are you opening Report Writer from inside Dynamics GP to make your edits? There are different methods depending on that answer. If working inside GP's Report Writer, is your instance licensed for Modifier with VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create any calculated field, just add Item Master table in reports table, select item master table and drag and drop the Tax Commodity field on report.
[image: add item master table in report]